# Java alternatives to loadLibrary or load Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, dll

I would like to know if there is any alternative to load a library more than System.LoadLibrary or System.load.

Due to the circustances I cant use them. Is there anyway in Java to specify the address where the dll has to be loaded?

thanks!

Comment: Why can you not use them? It may be helpful to know the bigger picture here :)

Comment: I can't use it because EMET is producing an error when I try to load a dll and I need to have EMET running.

Comment: Okay. Then it sounds like your issue is really with EMET. Perhaps you should post a question on that. It sounds like you would really fix the problem by doing that, instead of making a workaround.

Comment: The real question here is if there is any other way to load a dll whithout using loadLibrary or load. Thats the simple and real question. Thanks